# Package lplfitch and "Overfull \hbox"

Tags: boxes, proof-package

I get a huge lot of `Overfull \hbox` using Fitch diagrams, package `lplfitch`. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lplfitch}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\fitchprf{}{
\pline[1.]{???}[???]\\
\subproof{\pline[2.]{???}[]}{
\pline[17.]{???}[???]
}
\pline[18.]{???}[???]
}
\caption{Formal proof of...}\label{fig:aaa}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This example generates only one error.
I think it is connected with the indentation (for every level I get an error, base level excluded). Is it my error or is a known error of the package?

The PDF is simply perfect, but for every diagram I get 5 and more Warning...the only ones in my document, and thus it is disturbing.

I just noticed that there is a even smaller MWE, without figute:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lplfitch}

\begin{document}
$$
\fitchprf{}{
\pline[1.]{???}[???]\\
\subproof{\pline[2.]{???}[]}{
\pline[17.]{???}[???]
}
\pline[18.]{???}[???]
}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Warnings do not necessarily need to be a problem, especially `overfull` and `underfull` warnings. You should check the part of the page that they refer to, and if it looks ok, you can just ignore them.

Comment: @Marijn, the message is very generic, it gives only the last line of the diagram. Ignoring is not easy: if I have tens of warnings in texstudio, I can't see the real problems without scrolling.

Comment: The most important warnings are repeated in the end (_warning: there were undefined references_ or _labels may have changed, rerun to get cross-references right_ etc.) and the rest of the warnings can probably be skipped. If you really want to make sure you didn't miss anything important you can periodically (once per week for example) check the log file for all warnings to determine if they require action or not. And of course check the output pdf carefully for any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coding for the nested proofs in the package doesn't take too much attention to the accumulated widths, but a simple change is just to turn off tex warnings at that point, which doesn't affect the output, just the logging.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\renewcommand{\subproof}[2]{&\hfuzz\maxdimen\fitchprf{#1}{#2}\\}
\begin{document}

\[
\fitchprf{}{%
\pline[1.]{???}[???]\\%
\subproof{\pline[2.]{???}[]}{%
\pline[17.]{???}[???]%
}%
\pline[18.]{???}[???]%
}%
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the hack suppress  all the messages from `\subproof` or only a part?

Comment: @PeptideChain I am sure you meant "elegant and incisive code change" not "hack" :-) it affects all overfull box messages in a subproof but no other messages.

Comment: Sure. 1 line log instead of 20 lines log is a better life!